# No app icon in windows 10 native notification header in Electron

Tags: reactjs, electron

The place for the icon is empty.

The application itself has it, and everything is fine with the title too

**Code**

```
function showNotification () {
  new Notification({ title: NOTIFICATION_TITLE, body: NOTIFICATION_BODY }).show()
}
```

Comment: Found the issue? I have the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

You have to put the image inside `icon` property
But for me, i dont have application icon, dont know what happend.

Comment: This is not an answer